# Very Very Slow Query Update on Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, cpu-speed

Hi I wanted to ask for something about sql server, I'm getting a c # software that needs to update the data on a sql server with an update, Now my problem is that the Parameters to Update Recently (Codice Barcode) is present on a different file From the import, so I have to enter (Codice Barcode) with an update query, My problem is that I have to update more than 200'000 items. I wanted to know if there was a way to speed things up on a Sql Server 2014 now as it now takes a lot to import everything:

**Upgrade Query:**

```
SqlConnection conn = db.apriconnessione();
            String Query = "Update Articolo set CodiceBarcode='"+CodiceBarcode+"' where CodMarca='"+SiglaMarchio+"' and CodArt='"+CodiceArticolo+"' ";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

           conn.Close();
```

**Design of table articolo**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't use a SQL query to throw this update?

Comment: What do you mean? @McNets

Comment: Execute this query from SSMS instead of use C# code.

Comment: You could start by improving your code's security and using parameters instead of allowing SQL injections

Comment: i guess he means that he didn't want to iterate all lines from his file and call 200k update queries. He just wants to call one query that updates all records. Please clearify your question.

Comment: So really you have data in a file that you want to apply to data in a table. If you want to use C# to do this, investigate _table valued parameters_. But there are better ways to do this like importing the file into a staging table and running one single update to apply the data, which will be 100 times faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need an index on the columns in your where clause. Else it will be doing a table scan on each of your inserts.

Also you are doing things one at a time. Much quicker would be to bulk load the data and then so a single update.